# Erlang: case..of construct for function call return?

Tags: erlang, switch-statement, message-passing

The errors generated by the code are

```
2> X = "2".
"2"
3> case_:main(X).
main 50
sender 50
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  case_:sender/1 (case_.erl, line 14)
     in call from case_:main/1 (case_.erl, line 6)
4> Z = 2.
2
5> case_:main(Z).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  io:format/3
        called as io:format(<0.25.0>,"main ~p~n",2)
     in call from case_:main/1 (case_.erl, line 5)
6>
```

On the first try I tried to pass an string which made it a lot farther than the second try passing an integer. I'm not sure why this doesn't work.

The function call `sender(Input)` should return `{Data}` from the `receiver()` function call.

I definitely need the message passing part of the program since I'm trying to write a loop that takes messages, evaluates them and returns the result; but maybe the `case...of` statement could be thrown out.

```
-module(case_).
-export([main/1, sender/1, receiver/0]).

main(Input) ->
    io:format("main ~p~n",Input),
    case sender(Input) of
        {Data} ->
            io:format("Received ~p~n",Data)
    end.

sender(Input) ->
    io:format("sender ~p~n",Input),
    Ref = make_ref(),
    ?MODULE  ! { self(), Ref, {send_data, Input}},
    receive
        {Ref, ok, Data} ->
            {Data}      
    end.    

receiver() ->
    io:format("receiver ~n"),
    receive
        {Pid, Ref, {send_data, Input}} ->
            Pid ! { Ref, ok, Input + Input} 
    end.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Happily, badarg fix is easily done. [`io:format/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2) takes a list of terms as its the second argument. See:

```
(Erlang R15B02 (erts-5.9.2) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.2  (abort with ^G)
1> io:format("main ~p~n", 2).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  io:format/3
        called as io:format(<0.24.0>,"main ~p~n",2)
2> io:format("main ~p~n", [2]).
main 2
ok
```

Your second problem is that `?MODULE` just returns an atom of the current module's name. You'll want to send your message to a process. If you modify your code to look like so:

```
-module(case_).
-export([main/1, sender/2, receiver/0]).

main(Input) ->
    io:format("main ~p~n", [Input]),
    Recv = spawn(?MODULE, receiver, []),
    case sender(Recv, Input) of
        {Data} ->
            io:format("Received ~p~n", [Data])
    end.

sender(Pid, Input) ->
    io:format("sender ~p~n", [Input]),
    Ref = make_ref(),
    Pid ! { self(), Ref, {send_data, Input}},
    receive
        {Ref, ok, Data} ->
            {Data}
    end.

receiver() ->
    io:format("receiver ~n"),
    receive
        {Pid, Ref, {send_data, Input}} ->
            Pid ! { Ref, ok, Input + Input}
    end.
```

Then the interaction in the repl:

```
Erlang R15B02 (erts-5.9.2) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.2  (abort with ^G)
1> c("case_").
{ok,case_}
2> case_:main(2).
main 2
sender 2
receiver 
Received 4
ok
```